Equations for surface quotient singularities
Recall that a surface quotient singularity is given by $(\mathbb{C}^2/G,0)$ where $G$ is a small finite subgroup of $U(2)$. If $G$ is a subgroup of $SU(2)$, then the singularity is actually du Val singularities, i.e., of type $ADE$. In this case the singularity is given by $(f^{-1}(0),0)\subset \mathbb{C}^3$, where $f$ is given by e.g. in p.158 of https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/durfee15.pdf. However, I've seen that (I don't have a reference right now) for a quotient singularity which is not a du Val point, it is not a hypersurface singularity. Still, the germ $ (\mathbb{C}^2/G,0)$ should be embedded in some $\mathbb{C}^n$, and so it must be the singularity of the zero locus of some polynomials. Is there a reference to find such equations for a general surface quotient singularity?
